# Sci-fi short story about assassins who become targets

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read the story in the early eighties and remember it as being called “The Jackson Killers” but can’t find any reference to it. I believe it was in an anthology of sci-fi short stories.
Anyone recall it?

Comment: Assasins who become targets sounds like something by Robert Sheckley (7th Victim (1953), and I think a few other stories with the same idea), but I don't think there is a matching title.  Any chance that you remember more details (setting,character names etc) ?

Answer (score 19):

["The Jackson Killer"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93579), a short story by [Philip E. High](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_E._High), first published in [*New Worlds Science Fiction* #106, May 1961](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?154731), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_v36n106_1961-05.NovaAKv1.0/page/n73/mode/2up?view=theater). You may have read it in the 1977 paperback anthology [*The Best of British SF 2*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35756) edited by [Mike Ashley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Ashley_%28writer%29).

> "Bluntly you are a paid assassin?" The words were spoken by a slender, dark-haired man who had been introduced to him as David Kearsney.
>
> "Not an assassin, sir, a government agent from the Eliminator Corps."
>
> "A flowery title for the same thing, isn't it?" Kearsney's face was cold." You kill men."
>
> Lassen sipped his wine." Only a certain type of man — I'm a Jackson killer."
>
> There was a strained silence then someone laughed a little nervously. "My name's Jackson."
>
> Lassen made a deprecating gesture. "You confuse a name with a social malaise." He looked about him. "The work of the Corps is necessary, just as the elimination of pests is necessary."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> An Eliminator knew he was doomed from the moment he signed the necessary papers.
>
> There was no short-term-office in the Eliminator Corps for, after the first few killings, he was too mentally shocked to retire with his own conscience.
>
> After a few more, he had passed the point of no return and become to believe in his own God-like immunity.
>
> Throughout the Empire there was no task so demanding and no walk of life *so conducive to paranoia*. Inevitably the agent moved from latent to positive and became as those he was ordered to destroy.
>
> The Corps, who kept a tight check on its personnel, knew when an agent's usefulness was past and he was given what appeared to be a routine assignment.

Comment: oh that's a good story, well worth reading!

Comment: Nice story. I just read it and posted a [question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/22112/17) about it too.